# Foreign Key column missing

Tags: mysql, jdbc, google-apps-script, google-app-maker

I struggle to understand something that make no sense to me.

So I have a database under google app maker which have `relation` and `foreign_key`.

But one relation's foreign_key doesn't appear inside mysql terminal in Google Cloud Platform Cloud console / Google App Maker / Google App Script, but it works in appmaker.

I have a web app from google app script where I try to create Row using `jdbc`, but without the `foreign_key`, I can't finish what I started.

Today I have tried to add a new relation and it's foreign_key appears in the console.

I had already tried to contact the google support who don't know how to help me.

#### Things I tried:

I tried to rename a foreign_key to the foreign_key missing.

I tried to alter the sql table.

I tried to create manual a foreign_key

So Does anyone have any idea on how to bypass the foreign_key which doesn't appear?

Comment: Probably you have a many to many relationship. Being that the case, inside appmaker use the [relations api](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/scripting/server#working_with_relationships)

Comment: hello thank you to awnser my question, i have a many to one relation so the foreign_key should be on the many side but is not, google already linked me this , in google app script with jdbc i need to put the id of the column i want inside the foreign_key when i want to add a relation, but the foreign_key don't appear.

Comment: @Thescriv The id is usually ``idofthecolumn_fk``. Have you tried directly viewing the table in Google cloud console?[You need to add `@Morfin` or `@TheMaster` to notify users]

Comment: thank you to awnser, yes i already tried to see it, but the fk don't exist :( 
@TheMaster

Comment: @Thesc Can you show the create table syntax in console and appmaker fields, relations in appmaker through screenshots? You can add them to your question by [edit]ing it.

Comment: Also provide relevant jdbc code, mysql console code and  the error returned, if any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank @TheMaster & @Morfinismo for the help.

So i found the source of my problem.

When you create a Many to Many relation in Google App Maker the Foreign_Key will not appear, it will create a jointure table to save all fk.

> Imagine you have two table A and B and you create a Many to Many it will create a new tablea Called A_Has_B and it will contaign two Foreign_key A_fk and B_fk.